# How can I prove that this sequence is bounded?

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to prove that this sequence is bounded:
$${b_n} = {1 \over 2} + {1 \over {2*4}} + ... + {1 \over {2*4*2n}}$$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $b_{n}$ is less than the geometric series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (\frac{1}{2})^{n}$

Comment: Hint it looks like a sum of reciprocals of factorials with an extra two factor. Remember e is equal to the infinite sum of reciprocals of factorials. This would be an easier and far more natural comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${2 \over {2*4*..*2n}} \leq {2 \over {(2n-2)*2n}}={1 \over {2n-2}}- {1  \over {2n}}$$

Thus

$$2b_n ={2 \over 2} + {2\over {2*4}} + ... + {2\over {2*4*...*2n}}\leq{2 \over 2} + \left({1 \over {2}} -\frac{1}{4}\right) +\left({1 \over {4}} -\frac{1}{6}\right)+  ... + \left({1 \over {2n-2}} -\frac{1}{2n}\right) =\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2n} < \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: Great! how did you come up with this inequality? (first line)

Comment: @DanielGagnon  Backwards... I recognized $\frac{1}{(n-1)n}=\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}$ which appears in many telescopic sums. In general $\frac{1}{n(n+1)..(n+k)}$, where $k$ is fixed, is telescopic....

Answer (score 2):

Let $$a_n = \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \frac{1}{3!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!}$$

Let 
$$A_i = \frac{1}{i!}$$ 
$$B_i = \frac{1}{2^i \cdot i!}$$

Note that $B_i \leq A_i$ for all $i \geq 1$.

We can write $b_n$ and $a_n$ in sum form:

$$a_n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} A_k$$
$$b_n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} B_k$$

We also know that the sum of the reciprocals of the factorials $$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k$$ converges (in this case to $e-1$). Since all terms in both sequences are positive, $$\lim_{n \to +\infty} b_n = \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k$$ is less than $e-1$ (and greater than $0$), so it must converge as well.

EDIT: I think the solution works now. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: $b_2=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8}=\frac{5}{8}$, $a_2 = \frac{3}{2}$, $b_2 \not = \frac{a_2}{2^2}$

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the correction.